# Flush Order One To Many Unidirectional Mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a One To Many Mapping with '`Item`' class as parent and '`ItemSizeCost`' class as child.

I have added `@OneToMany` and `@JoinColumn` in parent class.

When I try to persist parent I see hibernate issue three sql statements

```
insert into item (category_id, description, name) values (?, ?, ?)
insert into item_size_cost (cost, item_id, size_id) values (?, ?, ?)
update item_size_cost set item_id=? where id=?
```

I want to understand the reason behind last two statements (insert into child and update child). After some googling, I found that reason may be related to flush order of hibernate but couldn't understand entirely. Anyone has any good links to understand Hibernate's flush order? Any explanation would be appreciated. I'm mentioning my classes below -

```
Item -


    @Entity
@Table(name="item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
            cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name="item_id")
    List<ItemSizeCost> itemSizeCostList;

    .....
}

ItemSizeCost - 

   @Entity
@Table(name="item_size_cost")
public class ItemSizeCost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    /*@JoinColumn(name="item_id")*/
    private Item item;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="size_id")
    private Size size;

    @Column(name="cost")
    private double cost;
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the last two statements is the bi-directional mapping and the fact that the foreign key can be null.

There is an excellent article about this topic from Vlad Mihalcea. He is a Hibernate commiter: https://vladmihalcea.com/merge-entity-collections-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. My problem is related to Unidirectional OneToMany mapping. Also when I said i did some googling, this is the article i was referring to - https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/. He mentions "hibernate's flush order" in OneToMany section but I still couldn't understand the whole flow.